# C Pass by reference string

Tags: c, function, reference, char, c-strings

I want to modify a string inside the function. My code is pretty easy:

```
#include <stdio.h>


void doSomething ( char **string )
{
  sprintf(string,"some string");
}  

int main ( void )
{
  char *origString = NULL;

  doSomething ( &origString );
  printf ( "%s\n", origString );

  return 0;
}
```

But this code doesn't work. I would really appreciate an explanation more than a solution, but solution is also welcome.

I really need to use sprintf function, because the idea is to add some other strings with %s.

Thanks!

Solved!

```
 #include <stdio.h>


void doSomething ( char **string )
{
   *string = malloc(strlen("some string") + 1); 
    sprintf(*string,"some string");
}  

int main ( void )
{
  char *origString = NULL;

  doSomething ( &origString );
  printf ( "%s\n", origString );
   free(origString); // Previously malloced in doSomething
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should compile with the warning flags

Comment: `sprintf` doesn't allocate memory for the string. You'll need to declare a character array in `main()` or use `asprintf`.

Answer (score 2):

`sprintf` takes a `char*` as its first argument, not a `char**`, so it should be `sprintf(*string,"some string");`. However `*string` will be `NULL` at that point, so that would still not work.

If you want the memory for your string to be allocated by the `doSomething` function, you will need to allocate the memory in that function. `sprintf` will not allocate any memory for you. So before you'd call `sprintf`, you'd need to allocate memory using `malloc` and make `*string` point to that memory. You should also be aware that users of your function then needs to free the memory once they're done with it.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
#include <stdio.h>


void doSomething ( char *string )
{
  sprintf(string,"some string");
}  

int main ( void )
{
  char origString[200];

  doSomething ( origString );
  printf ( "%s\n", origString );

  return 0;
}
```

this passes in a pointer to the first character in the string (array of 200 characters). The contents of this array can then be modified.

*EDIT*

With malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>


void doSomething ( char **string )
{
         const char * const x = "Some string ksdskjkj";
   *string = malloc(strlen(x) + 1 /* For the null characcter */); // Now origString will also point to this dynamic memory
    sprintf(*string,"some string");
}  

int main ( void )
{
  char *origString = NULL;

  doSomething ( &origString );
  printf ( "%s\n", origString );
   free(origString); // Previously malloced in doSomething
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user1042850 - See above - Pls show your appreciation

Comment: @user1042850 - Please tidy up the indentation

Comment: I don't understand you, what do you mean?

Comment: @user1042850 - so things line up nicely - makes easier to read. Would usually do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ed Heal's solution is correct but to keep it inline with how you were originally going you could have achieved the same result with this (albeit with a couple of warnings depending on your compiler settings):

```
#include <stdio.h>


void doSomething ( char **string )
{
    sprintf(string,"some string");
}

int main ( void )
{
    char * origString[200];

    doSomething ( origString );
    printf ( "%s\n", origString );

    return 0;
}
```

In C strings are literally arrays of characters. You were trying to pass a null pointer to the doSomething(). doSomething ( char **string ) takes an address to a char pointer so you don't need to pass it the address of origString (i.e. &origString ). All you need is to pass it the dereferenced pointer via doSomething ( origString ).

Comment: If you're going to downvote my answer you should at least mention that either the code doesn't work (it does work) or that my explanation was faulty and then correct it.